# integrating an xsd validator (lib or tool)

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am currently using a crossplatform c++ project (windows+linux) which will soon need an external xsd validator.

My plan is to:

- either find a c++ library which does xsd validation (possibly a complex task)
- or an existing tool which I could just launch as an external process (easier I believe; Xerces could be an option?)

I have a deep hierarchy of xsd files, so I need a solid tool for the job.

My question: I need some suggestions about some easy-to-integrate-yet-production-ready-solution.

My take for now is to use Xerces, the java version and just call it in a separate process.

Probably I need to wrap Xerces, since it seems to not allow xsd validation in the command line, directly, e.g. https://github.com/ndw/xjparse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xmllint` with the `--schema` option:

```sh
xmllint --noout --schema test.xsd test.xml
```

test.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="info" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

test.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>abc</info>
```